# Check if a Range has a Name using Excel.Interop in C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop, excel-addins

I am currently working on Excel Addin Application using C# and Excel Interop. 
I am looping through a range of cells. I am trying to check if a cell is Named or not.

But when I am trying to add a if condition there is exception thrown if the range is not named. The exception is

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

This is kind of wierd.

```
if(r.Name == null)
{
    item.name="Not named";
} else 
{
    item.name = r.Name.Name;
}
```

The exception is thrown at if condition itself, why does the Range object does not return null if it is not named ?

Is there a way to check if the range has a Name or not. I do not seem to find any other solution.

Any help in this regards is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The exception is thrown at if condition itself, why does the Range object does not return null if it is not named ?

That's just the way the Excel object model works, you'll get the same result if you try to access Range.Name from VBA code.

Your options would be:

- Catch the exception, e.g.

  ```
  public string GetRangeName(range As Range)
  {
      try
      {
          var name = range.Name;
          if (name == null) return null; // Won't happen in the current version of Excel, but who knows for a future version
          return name.Name;
      }
      catch(COMException)
      {
          return null;
      }
  }
  ```
- or, iterate through the `Names` collection of the Worksheet and its Workbook, looking for one that references the cell you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of this and was just thinking in usual programming ways.